# "Auxiliary" or "ancillary"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

I am trying to phrase something like:

> We argue that introducing these concepts is likely to achieve ancillary goals.

Should I use *auxiliary* or *ancillary* here? Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Depends what you mean, right? In the interest of concise clear writing though, if you are not sure which of these words to use, it could be an indication that you could find a word that is more direct and meaningful. How about "supportive"? Or "secondary"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Ancillary** carries with it the idea of support for main goals:

> providing necessary support to the primary activities or operation of an organization, institution, industry, or system : *the development of ancillary services to support its products.*

**Auxiliary** has connotations of supplementary or "extra" help:

> providing supplementary or additional help and support : *an auxiliary nurse | auxiliary airport staff.*

[NOAD]

Use whichever works best for your meaning.

Comment: Interesting, I would have exactly switched those two connotations...

Comment: @Billare: I'd have given the same connotations as Robusto, but [Merriam Webster](http://www.m-w.com/) basically gives both definitions for both words, even giving "auxiliary" as one of the definitions for "ancillary"...

Comment: @psmears, @Billare: All this means is that the line is getting blurred, and the two words are starting to be used interchangeably. It is worth noting that *ancillary* comes from the Latin *ancilla* (maidservant) while *auxiliary* comes from *auxilium* (help). The uses of auxiliary all seem to point to a "not part of the main thing, but extra" connotation. And, yes, we are making find distinctions here, but that is what the OP's question requires.

Comment: I tend to agree with Robusto's distinction in connotations, but it is very interesting to see the confluence (?) in meaning and usage we apparently see.

Comment: (Coming into the conversation much later)  For whatever it's worth, both of these get used in technical and military applications quite often, where _ancillary_ is always used in the context of supporting something else that's up and running, and _auxiliary_ has a connotation of "the primary thing may or may not be working/available at the time".

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of *ancillary* is also "additional, subsidiary".

> Paragraph 19 was merely ancillary to paragraph 16.

If you wrote "ancillary goals" to mean "additional goals", then "ancillary goals" seems fine, to me.